# Extract information from table with muliple pages with selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, dynamic-tables

I'm trying to extract some articles from a webside using Selenium in Python. However, I'm having a very difficult time doing so.

So far my code reads:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Open website
os.environ['PATH'] += r"C:\Users\BackUp HDL\AppData\Local\Programs"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://watchmedier.dk/latest/filteredsitesFilter=policywatch.dk&sitesFilter=shippingwatch.dk&sitesFilter=mobilitywatch.dk&sitesFilter=energiwatch.dk&sitesFilter=finanswatch.dk&sitesFilter=ejendomswatch.dk&sitesFilter=mediawatch.dk&sitesFilter=agriwatch.dk&sitesFilter=fodevarewatch.dk&sitesFilter=medwatch.dk&sitesFilter=kapwatch.dk&sitesFilter=itwatch.dk&sitesFilter=ctwatch.dk&sitesFilter=watchmedier.dk&sitesFilter=advokatwatch.dk") 
# Accept cookies
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@title='SP Consent 
Message']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
"//button[@title='Accepter']"))).click()
```

I would now like to add the the content of the table below to a file, i.e. make a loop that run over all the pages, and collects the information from "DATO", "ARTIKLE", and "SIDE" into a dataframe. I have tried to run for loops following some different online guides but I always end up with different errors (elements that cant be found, objects that isn't callable etc.).

Can someone please help me, how to move on?

Comment: in url you forgot `?` after `/filtered`. To load next page you can use url with `&pageNumber=2`, etc. After clicking `Accpeter` you have to go to `parent_frame()`

Comment: Link seems down

Answer (score 0):

If you had errors then you should show them in question.

---

First it needs to go back to `parent_frame()`. But code works also if you don't accept cookies.

You could load pages using urls with `"&pageNumber=..."` - it can be useful if you want to use `for`-loop to load only few pages.

To load all pages you can search `button` with `onclick="nextPage()"` and click it. Eventually you could run directly JavaScript `nextPage()` to load next page but this way you don't know if there is button to next page.

You can find all rows in table, and use `for`-loop to work with every row separatelly. You can use `[1:]` to skip first row with headers.

In every row you can use relative xpath (starting with dot `.`) to search cells only in this row.

It can be simpler to put all values in normal list and later convert all to DataFrame.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Open website
#os.environ['PATH'] += r"C:\Users\BackUp HDL\AppData\Local\Programs"
#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# --- accept (but it works also without acceptation) --

print('Load main page')

url = "https://watchmedier.dk/"
driver.get(url)

# Accept cookies
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@title='SP Consent Message']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Accepter']"))).click()
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()

# --- before loops ---

url = "https://watchmedier.dk/latest/filtered?sitesFilter=policywatch.dk&sitesFilter=shippingwatch.dk&sitesFilter=mobilitywatch.dk&sitesFilter=energiwatch.dk&sitesFilter=finanswatch.dk&sitesFilter=ejendomswatch.dk&sitesFilter=mediawatch.dk&sitesFilter=agriwatch.dk&sitesFilter=fodevarewatch.dk&sitesFilter=medwatch.dk&sitesFilter=kapwatch.dk&sitesFilter=itwatch.dk&sitesFilter=ctwatch.dk&sitesFilter=watchmedier.dk&sitesFilter=advokatwatch.dk&startDate=&endDate="

# load first page - if you use `while`-loop
driver.get(url)

all_results = []

# --- loops ---

page = 1

while True:
#for page in range(1, 4):
    print('--- page:', page, '---')
    
    # load page - if you use `for`-loop
    #driver.get(url + "&pageNumber=" + str(page))
               
    # get all rows in table
    all_rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@class="c-latest-news__table"]//tr')
    
    # process all rows except first with headers
    for number, row in enumerate(all_rows[1:], 1):
        
        #print('row:', number)
        print('.', end='')
        
        # get all columns in row - relative xpath 
        all_cells = row.find_elements_by_xpath('.//td')
        
        date = all_cells[0].text
        
        artikel = all_cells[1].find_element_by_xpath('.//a')
        artikel_text = artikel.text
        artikel_link = artikel.get_attribute('href')
        
        # count `span` and convert to `boolean` (`bool(0)` gives `False`)
        key = bool(len(all_cells[2].find_elements_by_xpath('.//span')))
        
        side = all_cells[3].text
        
        # put row data in list
        all_results.append( [date, artikel_text, artikel_link, key, side] )
        
    print() 
    
    # find button to next page
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@onclick]').click()
        page += 1
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception:', ex)
        break
    
    #if page > 3: break  # stop `while`-loop after 3 pages

# --- after loops ---

import pandas as pd

# convert all data to DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(all_results, columns=['Dato', 'Artikel text', 'Artikel link', 'Key', 'Side'])

print(df.to_string())
```

Result: (when I use `if page > 3: break` to stop after 3 pages.)

```
Load main page
--- page: 1 ---
..................................................
--- page: 2 ---
..................................................
--- page: 3 ---
..................................................

      Dato                                                                                                                 Artikel text                                                                Artikel link    Key           Side
0    03/12                                                                    Walgreens undersøger muligheder for salg af britisk enhed                  https://medwatch.dk/Medicinal___Biotek/article13527459.ece  False       MEDWATCH
1    03/12                                                          FDA udvider godkendelse af Eli Lillys antistofbehandling yderligere                  https://medwatch.dk/Medicinal___Biotek/article13527436.ece  False       MEDWATCH
2    03/12                                                                           Svensk regering opgiver modstand mod EU-mindsteløn                       https://policywatch.dk/nyheder/eu/article13527396.ece  False    POLICYWATCH
3    03/12                                                       Italien vil bruge 2,8 mia. euro til afskærmning for øgede energipriser     https://energiwatch.dk/Energinyt/Politik___Markeder/article13527349.ece  False    ENERGIWATCH
4    03/12                                                                   Ny sms sår tvivl om topchefs forklaring om slettede sms'er                    https://agriwatch.dk/Nyheder/politik/article13527312.ece   True      AGRIWATCH
5    03/12                                                                              USA: Statsansattes iPhones ramt af hackerangreb             https://itwatch.dk/ITNyt/Brancher/Sikkerhed/article13527166.ece  False        ITWATCH
6    03/12  Trods rekordkøb afviser A.P. Møller Holding investeringer i life science: "Et for langt skridt fra vores kompetencer i dag"            https://medwatch.dk/laboratorie___diagnostik/article13525353.ece   True       MEDWATCH
7    03/12                                                                                                    3i køber AMP ud af Esvagt                https://kapwatch.dk/nyheder/kapitalfonde/article13527079.ece   True       KAPWATCH
8    03/12                                                                                  Mette F. afventer proces om slettede sms'er                    https://agriwatch.dk/Nyheder/politik/article13527026.ece  False      AGRIWATCH
9    03/12                                             Finanstilsynet ser særlig og sjælden kontotype skabe ny debat om negative renter       https://finanswatch.dk/Finansnyt/Pengeinstitutter/article13526203.ece   True    FINANSWATCH
10   03/12                                                                             Vestas vælger tysk logistikpartner i Nordamerika             https://energiwatch.dk/Energinyt/Renewables/article13526999.ece   True    ENERGIWATCH
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. The code partly worked - it seems like the infomation from the first 3 columns isn't stored - only the links. Would it be okay, if I send a private message to you?

Comment: when I run code then I get all values from all columns. I add output in my answer. But it first get all values to list and after all pages create `DataFrame` - so if you stop code using `Ctrl+C` then it will not create `DataFrame`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am stuck once again, and are likely to give up. I would therefore like to hear, if you, @furas, maybe would be willing to write the code for me (I would of cause pay you) or you know somebody else that will?

Comment: if you have new problem then create new question on new page. You will have place to show all details.

Comment: I'm just convinced that I will not be able to write the code myself, so I'm looking for someone who will do it for me (I will of cause pay you). So instead of creating a new question, I wanted to ask you, as you have helped me out before

Comment: you can write on furas@tlen.pl